# Minimal period of the decimal expansion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I need help with the following proof-

For $p$ coprime to $10$, let $T$ be the minimal period of the decimal expansion of $1/p$ (For example, $p=11$, so $1/11=0.090909...$ and $T=2$).

Prove that the minimal period of the decimal expansion of $1/p$ is bigger than $log_{10}p$.

I don't know how to approach this question...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length $l$ of the minimal period of $1/p$ is the smallest number such that $ p$ divides $10^l-1$.  Here $l$ is a divider of Euler's totient function $\varphi(p)$.

We are hunting for big numbers with small $l$.

So clearly $p$ should be a prime which also divides some $10^n-1=99\dots99=9\cdot11\dots11$. That is, $p$ must be a repunit $R_n$, which is also prime.  For $R_n$ we clearly have $l=n$, but surely $\log_{10}(R_n)<n$ since $R_n<10^{n}$.

Comment: Why - "The length $l$ of the minimal period of $1/p$ is the smallest number such that $p$ divides $10^l−1$ "? and what do you mean by "Repunit"?

Comment: If $p$ is coprime to $10$ it surely won't be a divisor of any power of $10$.  But due to Euler's theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem, it will eventually be a divisor of $10^n-1$. For your first question refer to https://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/period.html.  It refers to repunits, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following $T=ord_p10 = M$ then $10^M=1modp$
$$10^M -1 = p*k $$ 
while $10^M>k>0$ and $k \in Z$, thus: $log M-1 = log(pk)$
$$M=log(pk+1)>log(p)$$

Comment: I don't understand,why $T=ord_{p}10=M$?